# A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object Singleton class C++

Tags: c++, singleton

I have a singleton class. I would like to assign a value to a structure member. But the compiler throwing an error as `A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object`.
Please help me, how to solve the same.

```
class abc{

    static abc* m_selfInst;
public:

    struct abcd{
        int a;
    }abcd;

abc* GetInstance();
};

abc* abc::m_selfInst = NULL;

abc* abc::GetInstance()
{
    if(m_selfInst == NULL)
    {
        m_selfInst = new abc();
    }
    return m_selfInst;
}
int main()
{
    abc *ab = abc::GetInstance(); //Error Occurs here
    abc::abcd.a = 5; //Error occurs here too
    //cout <<ab.abcd.a << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetInstance` should be `static` function.

```
static abc* GetInstance();
```

access to `a` should be with variable of type `abc`.

```
ab->abcd.a
```

struct `abcd` and object of type `abcd` named `abcd` is really confusing.
Probably it should be

```
struct {
    int a;
} abcd;
```

Comment: When I am making struct as `typedef struct` gthen I can not able to access the structure name from the main, so what shall I do?

Comment: :- Class name is missing from the drop down list and compiler throwing an error as `type name  is not allowed`. for an example, `typedef struct abcd{...};. `main(){ab->abcd.a=5;}`.At abcd the error is coming as `type name  is not allowed`

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak What are you doing? Why `typedef`? Use `struct struct_name {...} abcd;` where struct_name is the name of struct. May be you will try to read books about C++?

Comment: I got the answer. Thnaks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

```
abc *ab = abc::GetInstance();
```

the `GetInstance()` method must be declared `static`, otherwise it can only be called on an instance of `abc`.

```
abc::abcd.a = 5;
```

Here, `abc::abcd` is type. Presumably, you need to refer to the `abcd` *instance* of the `abc` *instance* pointed at `ab`:

```
ab->abcd.a = 5;
```

You should really refrain from giving instances and types the same name (as in `struct abcd` and instance `abcd`).

Comment: @ForEveR thanks. I got confused with all the `ab`, `abc`, and `abcd`s.